# CSS:How to place bullets of li exact from where ui element starts

Tags: css

I have removed margin and padding from ui element. But it creates problem for me as li's bullets are shifted further to the left from where ui starts. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you try google and/or `list-style-position: inside;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so...

```css
ul{
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-left:0;
  list-style-position:inside
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>I'm</li>
  <li>an</li>
  <li>unordered</li>
  <li>list</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

by Default list-style-position is outside, list-style-property decides that the list-item markers should appear inside or outside the content flow.

set it to inside

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-position.asp)